# Nextjs middleware fetch ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

In a dev mode this works no problem but once I run production mode the fetch fails. Whats wrong with this ? Any idea?

```
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();

  if (publicPaths.some((path) => url.pathname.includes(path)))
    return NextResponse.next();

  let session;
  try {
    session = await fetch(
      `${url.origin}${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_BASE_PATH}/api/auth/session`,
      {
        headers: req.headers,
      }
    ).then((res) => res.json());
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  url.search = new URLSearchParams(`callbackUrl=${url}`).toString();
  url.pathname = `/api/auth/signin`;

  return session?.user ? NextResponse.next() : NextResponse.redirect(url);
}
```

> [TypeError: fetch failed] { cause: [Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
> ::1:3000] }

Comment: I'd suggest you do `console.log(\`${url.origin}${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_BASE_PATH}/api/auth/session\`)` and see what URL you are actually requesting.

Comment: Yeah that was the first thing I've checked.

Comment: Then, examine the tracert to that host from your production server and see if the route is clear.  Then, lastly if you can see you are reaching the target host, then you'll have to do some sort of debugging on the target host.  There could be interference by a proxy or firewall in the hosting environment.

Answer (score 1):

By mistake I've run a build run with node v16 instead of v18 and it worked.
Checking the case node seems to be the problem here. So the code is okay.

https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1624

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40702